# Arabic keyboard layout sends ligatures as one character (Laa Problem)

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout, arabic

Ubuntu sends [Arabic ligature glyphs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arabic_alphabet#Ligatures) as a single glyph. For example, Laa+Alif ligature "لا" (U+0644, U+0627) is sent as "ﻻ" (U+FEFB), and similarly for (ﻷ، ﻵ، ﻹ).

STEPS TO REPRODUCE

1. Settings > Keyboard > Add default Arabic layout
2. Type "ﻻ" (i.e: "b" in QWERTY keyboards)

OBSERVED RESULT
Output is ﻻ (U+FEFB)

EXPECTED RESULT
Output is لا (U+0644, U+0627).

To clarify for English speakers, this is like having a key to type a ligature. Say that you want to press "b" to type two characters: `fi` but instead you get `ﬁ` as a single character. This is exactly what's happening with this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[X keyboard layout](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/X_keyboard_layout) sends [Arabic ligature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arabic_alphabet#Ligatures) glyphs as a single glyph. For example, Laa+Alif ligature "لا" (U+0644, U+0627) is sent as "ﻻ" (U+FEFB), and similarly for (ﻷ، ﻵ، ﻹ). This is due to a [known limitation](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/XKeyboardConfig/XKB2Dreams) in xkb which does not allow mapping a key to more than one character.

##### Workaround with X compose

The following solutions require X server restart. If you have `im-config` installed, you can use `im-config -n xim`. Alternatively, add the following to your [environment variables](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Environment_variables):

```
XIM=none
XIM_PROGRAM=/bin/true
XIM_ARGS=
GTK_IM_MODULE=xim
QT_IM_MODULE=xim
SHORT_DESC="X compose table"
```

However, since most QT-based programs do not have this issue, it is enough to add `export GTK_IM_MODULE=xim` to `~/.xsessionrc` or `~/.xprofile`.

##### Workaround with ibus

- Set ibus as an input method by running

  ```
  im-chooser
  ```

  or by setting the environment variables:

  ```
  GTK_IM_MODULE=ibus; QT_IM_MODULE=ibus; XMODIFIERS=@im=ibus
  ```
- Run `ibus-daemon` or `ibus-setup` if ibus is not set up.
- Use ar-kbd-m17n as ibus input method.